# Knockout JS - Observable doesn't update the View on Load

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, crossroadsjs

First of all, I'm a newbie with Knockout. Got some basic understanding. I'm using Crossroad for Routing

This is the current scenario. I get the value from the URL as param.route().plan. It does work fine

The Value is then set to an Observable in the view model. However, the binding doesn't work/value doesn't update when I navigate to this route from the previous using location.href = "checkout/gold" where gold is the plan. But if I reload the Page it does work fine.

PS : The View model does work as expected. I doubled confirmed with console.log

Now Some Code - Function which redirects to the problematic View Model

```
// Function Handling Subsription
        self.subscribe = function () {
            alert(self.selectedPlan());
            var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
            if (currentUser === null) {
                $('#loginBox').modal('show');
            } else { // Else redirect
                location.href = '#checkout/'+self.selectedPlan();
                // Redirect to Checkout page
            }
        } // Function ends here
```

The View Model which seems to Work

```
self.selectedPlan = ko.observable(params.route().plan);
```

View

```
<span data-bind="text:selectedPlan()></span>
```

Comment: What does `self` refer to? I guess you have to use `self.selectedPlan.subscribe(function(plan){ ... location.href = "#checkout/" + plan; ... })`

Comment: var self = this

Comment: You cannot apply subscribe function on parent object. You will have to manually create separate subscribe functions for every observable value, you need to watch

Answer (score -2):

Okay so got the answer. Maybe would help someone

Use computed observables in such cases. This guarantees binding in such cases

```
var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable('Bob');
    self.lastName = ko.observable('Smith');
    self.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
    });
```

Their documentations are pretty forward

Comment: What does `firstName`, `lastName` or `fullName` have to do with the problem in your question? How would anyone using crossroad.js find this helpful?

Comment: I was just citing an example. The issue was nothing related to Crossroads, but rather with the Observable type.

Comment: But if you solved it, why do you not simply post your code? That's how this site works. Answers must have to do something with the question. This answer is useless and you would probably downvote it yourself if somebody else had posted it.